Xcode fails to connect to iPhone
After the recent Xcode update, my Mac is no longer able to connect to my iPhone. I’ve tried everything I can think of: buying a new cable, updating both my Mac and iPhone, restarting both devices, and even creating a new Xcode project. However, I keep encountering the same errors:
First, I see this message:
Connecting to iPhone
Xcode will continue when the operation completes.

Then, it changes to:
Waiting to reconnect to iPhone
Previous preparation error: The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device.:The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device

Finally, this is the last message before it loop over an dover again:
iPhone may need to be unlocked to recover from previously reported preparation errors
<none>

Edit: Note that my iPhone is obviously unlocked the whole time
I’m completely stumped. I’ve never had these issues before. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do you have VPN on your Mac? Turn it off if so

no I dont have a vpn
